# Can we get Test Card to test ApplePay in BrainTree SDK?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, braintree, applepay

I have app in which I have to implement `Apple Pay + Braintree`.

I implemented Apple Pay as suggested by `BrainTree`.  In this,

```
[PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController canMakePayments] return me YES
```

But,

```
[PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController canMakePaymentsUsingNetworks:] returns me `NO`.
```

`Is BrainTree Provides this Test Card to test Apple Pay?`

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This link](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/ios+ruby/guides/apple-pay/testing-go-live) explains how to test Apple Pay with Braintree. So you will need to add an actual functional card to your Passbook. The card won't be charged but there are no test cards with Apple Pay when integrating with Braintree

Comment: Thanks lostIn Transit.